# How to adapt matrix strategy to event type?

Tags: unit-testing, github, github-actions

I have a workflow on GitHub to run unit tests on a Python application. I need the test to run for various Python versions *and* various OS versions. Right now the workflow looks like this:

```yaml
name: Python tests
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
  pull_request:
  release:
    types: [published]

jobs:
  release-strategy:
  push-pull-strategy:
  pytest:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: ["3.7", "3.8", "3.9", "3.10", "3.11"]
        os: [ubuntu-20.04, ubuntu-22.04]
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    steps:
      ...
```

This is a bit too heavy to be run for every pull request on dev, but on the other hand we really want to run all these tests before a release in made, so we would like to run the full matrix strategy only upon release, and run a smaller subset for all other cases, eg `["3.7", "3.11"]` and `[ubuntu-20.04, ubuntu-22.04]`.

Is there a way to implement this behavior without having two separate workflows?

Comment: you could add an intermediate step that calculate the strategy matrix based on your condition. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, I realized I could simply add a job containing the selection logic as bash instructions, gonna post my solution soon, thank you for your input though!

Comment: yes, exactly! +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized I could describe this logic in a previous job using standard bash instructions (instead of trying to use the workflow logic). My solution looks like this:

```yaml
name: Python tests
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
  pull_request:
  release:
    types: [published]

jobs:
  select-strategy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      python-versions: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.python-versions }}
    steps:
      - id: set-matrix
        run: |
          if [ ${{ github.event_name }} == "release" ]; then
            echo "python-versions=[\"3.7\",\"3.8\",\"3.9\",\"3.10\",\"3.11\"]" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          else
            echo "python-versions=[\"3.7\",\"3.11\"]" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          fi
  pytest:
    needs: select-strategy
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: ${{ fromJson(needs.select-strategy.outputs.python-versions) }}
        os: [ubuntu-20.04, ubuntu-22.04]
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    steps:
      ...
```